# Issue adding rows into dataset of PowerBI using API

Tags: powerbi

I'm adding 2 rows into dataset inside a PowerBI group.

```
POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/datasets/{datasetId}/tables/FuelSurcharge/rows HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJ...
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: api.powerbi.com
Content-Length: 282
Expect: 100-continue

{"rows":[
{"Customer":"PMPBBLP1","Carrier":"STE","FreightCharges":7.89,"FuelSurcharge":0.94,"FuelSurchargePercent":0.1191381495564005069708491762},
{"Customer":"PMPBBLP1","Carrier":"STE","FreightCharges":7.56,"FuelSurcharge":0.9,"FuelSurchargePercent":0.119047619047619047619047619}]}
```

It's all good except of instead of adding 2 rows it adds 1 row which is sum of all values. Am I doing something wrong or it's a bug in API?

**Update:**
The workaround was to add another column: Id and populate it with a unique value. Is it expected?

**Update2:**
The workaround has stopped working. :S

Answer (score 0):

Your rows do not have any values that is unique across the two records.  Power BI aggregates by default.  If you create a report with a table in it that has fields Customer and FreightCharges. Then in the fields well (where you define the fields in your visualization) right click the customer field and select 'do not summarize'.  Do you see two rows or one?  Probably two rows.  If you'd like to show detail values, suggest you insert something that's unique across the rows (like an id or a date/time stamp). Then it's easier to tell what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Except of Customer and Carrier other fields are different. I don't understand why Power BI would choose to aggregate the rows. What is the logic? I don't see anywhere where I could disable it. Anyway, seems to me a very dodgy behavior of Power BI

Comment: the link below shows a picture of where to find the 'do not summarize' feature: https://support.powerbi.com/knowledgebase/articles/471200-change-the-aggregation-in-a-chart-sum-average-m  It's on the right click menu on a field.

Comment: I think it's only available in powerbi designer. At least I don't see those options in the app.powerbi.com. I created dataset schema from the api.